# Calculating diversity indices using SQL in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I want to be able to calculate community diversity indices (ie Shannon diversity, evenness, etc.) using a database I have created in MS Access.  The table from which the data will be drawn from has individual samples as rows, species as columns, and raw abundance values for each species in each cell. From what I've read, the easiest way to do this would be with a calculated field in the table itself, but this is not an option for this dataset (the max number of columns is 255 and I conveniently have 255 species). Is there some way to perform these calculations using SQL queries?  Ideally I would be able to add some button to the data entry form and have these indices be calculated automatically and added to a report.

Comment: I am not familiar with diversity indices. In terms of basic data structure, 255 is a lot of columns and makes it very difficult to work with the data. I would advise to restructure the data to less columns maybe like: SampleNumber, SampleDate, Species, and RawAbundanceValue. This way you can query or add calculated columns with less complexity.

Comment: Restructure data or use VBA for calcs. Manually restructuring will be a rather tedious process. Could use VBA to accomplish.